# What should I do with an unused C wire when installing a thermostat?

Tags: hvac, thermostat

Replacing a Carrier programmable with a Honeywell RTH6350D1000. Carrier had blue/gray wire in the C connector. Honeywell does not have a C connector. In install book "Advanced" wiring it says to ignore the c wire.

Answer (score 3):

You can either cap the wire with a twist-on wire connector (or similar device), or clip the uninsulated portion of the wire off. Once the uninsulated portion of the wire is covered, you can just tuck it away.

To be extra safe, you can disconnect the other end of the wire from the furnace.

Comment: I would also put a small wire connector or piece of electrical tape over the end of the clipped wire (if left energized). There's still a (small) chance the blunt end of the wire making contact with something and causing problems.